# paginate results searchkick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination

So i have this pagination working on my tables

```
.page(params[:page]).per(50)
```

Heres what i have for my search

```
@events = Event.search params[:search], suggest: true, partial: true, misspellings: {distance: 2}

if @events.results.any?
  render '/results'
else
  render '/noresults'
end
```

this is how i currently display it on my view

```
  <% @events.each do |event|%>
```

Thanks for any help!

Sam

Answer (score 2):

Pagination( As per the documentation)
https://github.com/ankane/searchkick

Plays nicely with kaminari and will_paginate.

```
# controller
@products = Product.search "milk", page: params[:page], per_page: 20
```

View with kaminari

```
<%= paginate @products %>
```

View with will_paginate

```
<%= will_paginate @products %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this using the "pagy" gem

### Gemfile

`gem 'pagy', '~> 6.0' # omit patch digit`

### config/initializers/pagy.rb

```
require 'pagy/extras/searchkick'
Searchkick.extend Pagy::Searchkick
```

### Model

`extend Pagy::Searchkick`

### Controller

`include Pagy::Backend`

### Controller Actions

````
collection = Event.pagy_search(params[:search])
# multi models
collection = Searchkick.pagy_search(params[:search], models: [Event, SomethingElse])
# paginate it
@pagy, @response = pagy_searchkick(collection, items: 10)```


# More info in their official docs here:
# https://ddnexus.github.io/pagy/quick-start/
````